# Teamcity is displaying green icon even the tests are failed

Tags: testing, nunit, teamcity

Tests are failing but teamcity is showing green sign instead of red. Any idea what setting I am missing in configuration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you take a picture of your build steps and then post it please?

Comment: Have attached the pic..You can see that all tests are failed but the build sign is in green color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to enable "Fail build if... at least one test failed" option at General Settings of your build configuration.